# Drop a column when the schema changes in ORMLite

Tags: android, database, schema, upgrade, ormlite

I am working with Android and ORMLite. I am newbie and I upgrading the database to the Version 2. I have the class “Auto” and need to drop the column Alias.

```
    @DatabaseTable(tableName = "Auto")
public class Auto {

    public static final String ALIAS                 = "alias";
    public static final String PLACA                 = "placa";


    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = "ID")
    private int id;
    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, columnName = ALIAS)
    private String alias;
    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, columnName = PLACA)

    public Auto()
    {
        //ORMLite needs a no-arg constructor
    }

    public Auto(String alias, String placa) {
        this.alias                  = alias;
        this.placa                  = placa;
    }

…..
…..
}
```

I change the class Auto to…

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "Auto")
public class Auto {

    public static final String PLACA                 = "placa";


    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = "ID")
    private int id;
    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, columnName = PLACA)

    public Auto()
    {
        //ORMLite needs a no-arg constructor
    }

    public Auto(String alias, String placa) {       this.placa                  = placa;
    }

…..
…..
}
```

I need to know if ORMLite automatically drops the column Alias when execute “onUpgradeMethod” or I have to do manually like this.

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
   if(oldVersion == 1) {
   try {
      Dao dao;
      dao = getAutoDao();
      dao.executeRaw("ALTER TABLE `Auto` DROP COLUMN alias;");

   } catch (SQLException e) {
      Log.e(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "Error ", e);

   }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This links help me to solve it.

[Drop column in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442147/how-to-delete-or-add-column-in-sqlite)

[FAQ SQLite 11](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q11)

[Delete column from SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938048/delete-column-from-sql-table/5987838#5987838)

[save data before table upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046451/ormlite-save-data-before-table-upgrade)

[Drop table if it already exists and then re-create it?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/204892/drop-table-if-it-already-exists-and-then-re-create-it)

> SQLite has limited ALTER TABLE support that you can use to add a column to the end of a table or to change the name of a table. If you want to make more complex changes in the structure of a table, you will have to recreate the table. You can save existing data to a temporary table, drop the old table, create the new table, then copy the data back in from the temporary table.
>
> For example, suppose you have a table named "t1" with columns names
>   "a", "b", and "c" and that you want to delete column "c" from this
>   table. The following steps illustrate how this could be done:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION; 
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1_backup(a,b);
INSERT INTO t1_backup SELECT a,b FROM t1; 
DROP TABLE t1; CREATE TABLE t1(a,b); INSERT INTO t1 SELECT a,b FROM t1_backup;
DROP TABLE t1_backup; 
COMMIT;
```

The possible solution according to Phil's comments is this. [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046451/ormlite-save-data-before-table-upgrade)

> So your choices are:
>
> 1. leave things as they are,
> 2. add a new column, copying all the data from old to new as part of the upgrade, and just ignore the old column altogether, or
> 3. Use a drop/create strategy to upgrade: back up the data from table into a temporary table, drop the table, re-create it as you'd like it
>      to be, copy all the data back into it, and finally drop the temporary
>      table.
>
> Database upgrades are always nervous affairs (need lots of error
>   handling, lots of testing), frankly if the name is the only thing that
>   concerns you, I'd leave it alone (option 1). If you really need to
>   change it then option 2 is low risk but leaves a 'dead' column and
>   data lying around. Option 3 may be your choice if, for example, the
>   data is a significant percentage of the overall database size.

I decided to delete the data from the column but don't drop the column, that is similar to solution 2.